# Haskell Expression Equivalents

Tags: haskell

I'm a very new Haskell learner. I have a working expression:

```
do x <- try parseA <|> parseB
   return x
```

which appears to work perfectly (I'm using the `Parsec` package, but I hope this question has nothing to do with its functionality, as far as I know `<|>` is a Parsec-defined infix operator). `parseA` and `parseB` both have the `Parser Foo` monad type, as does the whole expression.

Based on what I've read so far, it seems this should be equivalent to

```
do return (try parseA <|> parseB)
```

and

```
do return $ try parseA <|> parseB
```

but none of the latter compile, they complain of mismatched types (errors below).

My other attempt to rewrite this, as

```
(try parseA <|> parse B) >>= return
```

seems to work. But if I've misunderstood this too, please say.

So my question is, can someone explain why the first three are different. I'm confused why they aren't equivalent. What am I missing?

---

Errors (in case this is relevant, though fwiw I'm not looking to 'fix' my code - I have a working version, I'm looking to understand how the versions differ):

```
do return (try parseA <|> parseB)
```

gives

```
parse.hs:76:11:
    Couldn't match expected type ‘Foo’
                with actual type ‘Text.Parsec.Prim.ParsecT
                                    [Char] () Data.Functor.Identity.Identity Foo’
```

and

```
do return $ try parseA <|> parseB
```

gives

```
parse.hs:76:3:
    Couldn't match type ‘Text.Parsec.Prim.ParsecT
                           [Char] () Data.Functor.Identity.Identity Foo’
                  with ‘Foo’
    Expected type: Parser Foo
      Actual type: Text.Parsec.Prim.ParsecT
                     String
                     ()
                     Data.Functor.Identity.Identity
                     (Text.Parsec.Prim.ParsecT
                        [Char] () Data.Functor.Identity.Identity Foo)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Do Notation Desugaring

The [rules for do notation desugaring](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/do_Notation#Translating_the_bind_operator) imply that

```
do x <- try parseA <|> parseB
   return x
```

is equivalent to

```
(try parseA <|> parse B) >>= return
```

## `($)` versus `(>>=)`

Since `(=<<)` is a flipped version of `(>>=)`,  both are equivalent to

```
return =<< (try parseA <|> parse B)
```

This implies that the only difference between your correct version and `return $ try parseA <|> parse B` is the difference between `(=<<)` and `($)`, whose types are:

```
($)   :: (a -> b)   -> a   -> b
(=<<) :: (a -> m b) -> m a -> m b
```

You can see that `($)` is not a replacement for `(=<<)`, but perhaps you can also see that they are somewhat similar. One way to look at it is that `(=<<)` – and thus also `(>>=)` – is a kind of function application that applies "monadic functions" of type `a -> m b` for some Monad `m` to "monadic values" of type `m a` for some Monad `m`, whereas `($)` is the usual kind of function application that applies functions of type `a -> b` to values of type `a`.

## Monad Laws

One of the [monad laws](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.2/docs/Prelude.html#t:Monad) is that

```
k >>= return = k
```

This implies that

```
(try parseA <|> parse B) >>= return
```

can also be written as

```
try parseA <|> parse B
```

which means your original form using do notation can also be written that way.

Comment: Thank you, this was the tip off I needed to understand. The other bit that I was missing is that <- is not just an assignment, it strips the Monad and returns the underlying type, so x <- y then foo x is not equivalent to foo y. I appreciate the comprehensive answer, Rein.